# useEffect with hook gives me a warning message

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setSingleFieldData({ ...singleFieldData, id: uuidv4() });
  }, []);
```

basically when the component loads I want to add to singleFieldData an id using uuidv4, I'm using useEffect like "componentDidMount" and using empty brackets, but I get this warning:

```
/src/components/FormBuilderPage/utils/FieldGenerator.js
  Line 64:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'singleFieldData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setSingleFieldData(s => ...)' if you only need 'singleFieldData' in the 'setSingleFieldData' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

adding singleFieldData to the dependacy doesn't work because I only want it to run once at the render what should I do to get rid of that warning

Comment: As an aside, it is generally recommended to split up your state objects where possible - that is, avoid using objects in `React.useState()` and instead try to use smaller pieces of data, where possible. `setUUID` instead of `setSingleFieldData`, for example.

Comment: Additionally, using setState within a useEffect without wrapping it in an if is almost certainly going to cause issues. Try to refactor your code to not rely on the useEffect if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When wanting to refer to the `prevState`, React `useState` provides a callback function version that you have to use:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSingleFieldData(prevSingleFieldData => ({
        ...prevSingleFieldData, id: uuidv4() 
    }));
}, []);
```

[Docs - Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

There is a case that you can do this when setting the initial state itself.